# How to initialize global variables of a package in a lazy manner, from the user input?

Tags: go, package

There're multiple packages in my projects: the main one and secondary ones. The main one accepts input from the users and initializes some variables in itself.
The secondary packages contain some global variables that can only be initialized once the one of the "main" package have been, and not earlier.

I'm aware of the function "init()" of a package but this won't work in my case because it's not capable on initializing data in a lazy way, and with some arguments or data from the outside. Whereas this is what I want.

```
    //main package

    var (
        a1 int
        a2 float
        a3 string
        a4 MyStruct
        a5 MyStruct2
    )

    func main() {
        //process user input
        //...........
        //some other stuff


        // I want that by this point, the global variables of package2 to have been initialized
        // **based on** the processed user input from above
        //namely, before the first access to the package
        package2.Func1()

        // I want that by this point, the global variables of package3 to have been initialized
        // **based on** the processed user input from above
        //namely, before the first access to the package
        package3.Func11()

    }
```

### Is there a solution for this?

I could've a function "initData()" in the packages package2 and package3, but how would I ensure that it won't be forgotten to be called as the very first function, in a mandatory way, before calling any other functions of a package?

Comment: If you want to assign the values on demand, and ensure that they as assigned, you need to put in the safeguards to do this.

Comment: @JimB what are safeguards?

Comment: _plural noun: safeguards -- a measure taken [...] to prevent something undesirable_, i.e. check that the values are set before doing anything, require calling an initialization function, just panic if things are not correct, etc.

Comment: the `main` package has an `init()` too.  that might be a good place to call `initData`.

Comment: @JimB - a downside - I would have to insert them into each function in package2/3. I need a better solution

Comment: @DanielFarrell how would that be different  from calling `initData()` from `main()` itself then?

Comment: Functionally, it really isn't.  "The secondary packages contain some global variables that can only be initialized once the one of the "main" package have been, and not earlier." The more I think about that statement the more it seems like a bad organization of data.  Why are they global  and in that package if their values are dependent on the state of their consumer?

Comment: @DanielFarrell it seems wrong to you. Don't think too much.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use an init function in main.go

```golang
func init(){
    // get user input and set variables

    // call package 2 and 3 after setting the variables in main
    package2.Func1()
    package3.Func1()

}

func main(){
    // everything is setup properly when code in this main function is launched
}
```

Comment: that won't work because I expect user input in main. By user input I don't mean command line arguments; How's that even different from calling those 2 functions in main?

Comment: then i don't understand your problem, simply get your user input in main and then set the variables in the other packages, you use init to set things before main is called which seems like what you want because you want to initialize variables before main is ran

Comment: Yes. But I'd prefer to do it in some more correct way. Otherwise what if someone  decided to call any function from package2 before the variables had been initialized in it?

Comment: tell your users to initialize things before using them that is all you can do,

Comment: bad advice.......

Comment: telling users how to initialize a library is common, i see no other way to do it seems like you have a circular dependency between your packages, if you really need to be sure move the code from package 2 and 3 to package 1 that is the only clean way to do it

Comment: Won't work for me

Comment: then what you want is not possible to my knowledge